# How to measure developer build time

Tags: visual-studio, build, profiling

I wanted to write a small app that would sit in my taskbar and monitor what Visual Studio was doing all day.  Specifically, what I really want to figure out is how long I spend waiting on Visual Studio to build my solution each day.

Could someone point me in the right direction.  Is there something in the Visual Studio SDK that would help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this is just for curiosity, I'd go with an easy option...

One potential would be to just make a pre-build and post-build script for your project, and log the start/stop of your build times.

You could then just parse the log and figure out the total time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My solution has ~15 projects.  Can I do this on a solution level, or do I need to do it for each project?

Comment: It depends on what you want to measure.  However, wrapping every project (although you could use the same script for this) would be the safest, since not every project gets built every time you "build", unless you're always doing full builds.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is only (or mostly) used for development, you could record the CPU time used by the idle thread in the Task Explorer at the start and the end of the day.  Comparing the difference to the wall clock time will give you the total CPU used.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to copy the build log into a new text file within VS, search for Time Elapsed within the file, copy all the occurrences into excel select the cell under the build times for each of the projects and press the Sigma symbol to add them all. It takes 15s to do :-)